# 301 Redirect to URL with query strings

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect one URL to another URL. They are different domains, but both have query strings in their URLs. The sample URLs are:

Redirect: 
olddomain/faculty/profile?uID=123

to:
newdomain/Faculty?id=024

This is what I've placed in the .htaccess file and it does not work (all modules necessary are installed and activated as there are other 301's without query strings that work without issue):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.olddomain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^uID=123$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^faculty/profile$ http://newdomain/Faculty?id=024 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `http://` also:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^uID=123$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^faculty/profile$ http://newdomain/Faculty?id=024 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

And make sure this rule is placed at top just below `RewriteEngine On`.

Comment: I should have clarified that; I do have `http://`, but it's still not working. I've edited my original query.

Comment: Do you have some other rules in this file? Can you move this to top just below `RewriteEngine On` line?

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Do you know why? I have other Rewrite conditions in there for my CMS and I had placed this chunk of code at the bottom of that.

Comment: Yes I have seen that mistake many times with WP rules also :)